# Tried jointly distributed random variables. Please Check

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that X, Y, and Z are jointly distributed random variables, that is, they are defined on the same sample space. Suppose that we also have the following.

E(X)=5

E(Y)=-3

E(Z)=-7

Var(X)=49

Var(Y)=32

Var(Z)= 47

Compute the values of the expressions below.

E(-2Z-4)=

E((5z-3X)/4))=

Var(5Y+2)=

E(-5Z^2)=

I tried to substitute 1.E(-2Z-4)= -2(-7)-4=10

2.E((5z-3X)/4))= (5(-7)-3(5))/4= -12.5

3.Var(5Y+2)=5(32)+2=16.2

4.E(-5Z^2)=-5(-7)^2=-245

Is this correct?

Please Help!

Comment: Yes due to the linearity of $E$.

Comment: E((5z-3X)/4))= (5(-7)-3(5))/4= -12.5

Var(5Y+2)=5(32)+2=16.2

E(-5Z^2)=-5(-7)^2=-245

Is this correct?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) It's hard to read your questions.  Please use MathJax to format your math.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  No for the last two questions.

Comment: I have edited the question and I have tried to solve it, could you please take a look at it

Comment: 1. I don't see how you've typeset it MathJax.  For most of the math in the question, it's as simple as adding a surrounding pair of `$`. 2. In my previous comment, I've said that for the last two question, the answer is no.  It's because you don't have linearity as in the first two parts.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Is it an assignment question?

Comment: Yes it is......for 4th is it $-665.98$ (correct to 2 decimal place)??

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question so that it's using MathJax.  I suppose that in your notes, there're two formulae $Var(aX + b) = a^2 Var(X)$ and $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$.  Use these two formulae to correct your answers for the last two parts, and consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!